# Getting null bytes out of Windows shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

The code in question:

```
mov ebx, fs:30h
```

Consequent shellcode:

```
648b1d30000000
```

I can't seem to figure out how to write this without null bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own answer (of using the destination register to construct the offset for the load) works but wastes some bytes.

The `30h` can fit in a `disp8` in an addressing mode instead of an `imm8` in a separate instruction.

```
  xor ebx, ebx
  mov ebx, fs:[ebx+30h]    ; or [rbx+30h] in 64-bit code.
```

Some register is needed as part of the addressing mode; there's no way to use a `disp8` without a register.

---

In 64-bit code, RIP-relative addressing doesn't help for shellcode (which could end up injected at any unknown absolute address).  But it is possible to generate a `30h` offset as RIP+rel32 == 30h if you know the absolute address the code will run from, and it's within +-2GiB of `30h`.

YASM allows relative references to absolute addresses.  (NASM doesn't like it.)

```
  mov  ebx, [fs: rel 30h]
```

Disassembly of `yasm -felf64 foo.asm && ld foo.o` on Linux, which makes a non-PIE executable (not position-independent, can only run with `.text` at the address it's linked for.) `objdump -drwC -Mintel` output:

```
  401000:    64 8b 1d 29 f0 bf ff    mov  ebx,DWORD PTR fs:[rip+0xffffffffffbff029]   # 30
```

But NASM makes the cowardly complaint: "foo.asm:1: warning: absolute address can not be RIP-relative [-w+ea-absolute]" and assembles it to a `[disp32]` absolute address (which in x86-64 requires a SIB byte to encode.)

```
  401000:    64 8b 1c 25 30 00 00 00      mov    ebx,DWORD PTR fs:0x30
```

IIRC, with some trickery one can convince GAS to emit RIP-relative addressing of an absolute address.

If Windows has a relocation-entry type for reaching an absolute address via a relative reference, it could also support what YASM does, in code that isn't LargeAddressAware so the rel32 can reach.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
xor ebx, ebx
add ebx, 30h
mov ebx, fs:[ebx]
```

Comment: Looks fine, but you could remove the `add` and put the offset back in the memory operand